# Find image of matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, gaussian-elimination

> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}7&5&1\\-8&-6&0\\-3&-2&-1\end{pmatrix}$ find Im(A).

My attempt:

We know that $Im(A)=\{B=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^3|Ax=B, x\in \mathbb{R^3}\}.$

So then I try solving it with Gauss:

$\begin{array}{l}\begin{bmatrix}7&5&1&\vdots&a\\-8&-6&0&\vdots&b\\-3&-2&-1&\vdots&c\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow[{L_3=-L_3+\frac{-3}7L_1}]{L_2=\frac{-1}2L2+\frac{-4}7L_1}\\\begin{bmatrix}7&5&1&\vdots&a\\0&\frac17&-\frac47&\vdots&-\frac b2-\frac47a\\0&-\frac17&\frac47&\vdots&-c-\frac37a\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow[{L_3=7L_3+L_2}]{L_2=7L_2}\\\begin{bmatrix}7&5&1&\vdots&a\\0&1&-4&\vdots&-\frac72b-4a\\0&0&0&\vdots&-7c-7a-\frac72b\end{bmatrix}\end{array}$

then from the last equation we get: $\boxed{a=-c-\frac{b}{2}}$

so now.... what will my vector $B$ will be? Because if I write it in this form I will get a 0 at the bottom and that's not good

Comment: What you have tried is for solutions of a system of equations not for the image of a matrix.

Comment: That's the method they taught me at university, man, but I'm missing something

Comment: @RhythmInk Then what method do you suggest me to use to determine the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your answer: the symbol $b$ has two distinct meanings.

Anyway, assuming that your computations are correct (I didn't check it), the conclusion is that $$\operatorname{Im}(A)=\left\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,\middle|\,a=-c-\frac b2\right\}=\left\{\left(-c-\frac b2,b,c\right)\,\middle|\,b,c\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$

Comment: but my computation are correct  but the answer is wrong and i don't get why, is there a problem with the method?

Comment: Why do you say that your answer is wrong?

Comment: Because on wolfram alpha they say that basis should be: $(5,-6,-2),(7,-8,-3)$. and that's the answer in my book too

Comment: And… ? It's the **same** space! I mean:$$\left\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,\middle|\,a+\frac b2+c=0\right\}=\bigl\langle(5,-6,-2),(7,-8,-3)\bigr\rangle.$$

Comment: Why you used scalar product for that? to determine that it's the same space?

Comment: I am **not** using a scalar product. If $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k$ are vectors, $\langle v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\rangle$ is the vector space spanned by them.

Comment: if I write them as $a = -\frac b2 -c\implies (a,b,c)=(-\frac b2 -c, b, c)=b(-1/2,1,0)+c(-1,0,1)$? how does that result into that?

Comment: Since $(5,-6,2)$ and $(7,-8,-3)$ are linearly independent vectors of the space that I mentioned, whose dimension is $2$, then they span it.

Answer (score 0):

The image is determined when you have a set of vectors which span it.

The *columns* of the matrix $A$ are a spanning set for the image, as these are the images of the unit vectors $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$.

If you apply Gaussian elimination to these columns (rather than to the rows, as you have done), you will find the basis: $(1,0,-1)^T, (0,2,-1)^T$. These define the plane $x + \frac{y}2 +z = 0$ supplied by Juan Carlos Santos in his answer above.